# Python & QT: creating a rollover help area

Tags: python, qt, nuke

I've got a UI that has gotten complex enough that the user can use a little help. I tried tooltips, but I don't like how they create UX distractions. What I'd like is to have an area where help always appears, with text that changes depending on where you hover the mouse.

What's the most efficent way of handling this? Subclassing tooltips? I thought about eventFilter, but I'm using it already to capture keypresses for QTextEdit boxes, and I'm not sure how I can make it work for every object anyway. I'm into new territory for me, so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Experimenting with using the eventFilter set to QEvent.Enter, and passing the help text in the whatsThis(). It works, but I'm not sure if I'm going to run into ugly conflicts. Still would love any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't done exactly what you're interested in, I have a pretty good idea of how I would approach it (at least initially), and it does involve using your own event filter object. Here are the basics:

1. Implement your own `QObject` subclass to be the event filter. This should take and store the widget instance you want to use to display your help text (say, a `QLabel`).
2. On your event filter object, implement `eventFilter` to look for `QEvent::Enter` events and set the help text appropriately, but not consume the event. You will need to come up with a system for mapping the object emitting the event (i.e. the object the cursor is over) to the help text that should be displayed.
3. Instantiate your filter and use `installEventFilter` to add it to each of the widgets you want to trigger help text displays.

Here's some skeleton code:

```python
class HelpTextFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, helpTextWidget):
        super(HelpTextFilter, self).__init__(helpTextWidget)
        # Could call self.parent() to get this every time instead of
        # storing it, but that's potentially a lot of method calls.
        self.helpTextWidget = helpTextWidget

    def eventFilter(self, sender, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
            # Get the help text for 'sender' here...
            self.helpTextWidget.setText(helpText)
        return False

# Registration
evFilter = HelpTextFilter(helpTextDisplayWidget)
for widget in widgetsThatNeedHelpTextDisplayed:
    widget.installEventFilter(evFilter)
```

Hope that helps you some.